# Can I retract a Suggested Edit vote?

Tags: discussion, reviewing

Sometimes when reviewing suggested edits, some users (well, for all I know, just me) can sometimes accidentally hit the wrong option - Approve when they meant to reject and vice versa.

Is there a way to undo this and vote correctly? If not, can someone explain why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, once you vote, it is a binding vote. The system is not set up for vote-takebacks in that sense. It's partially design, and partially because you are supposed to make sure that you review things carefully and accurately to avoid people robo-reviewing just for badges and the like. (See also [review audits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157121/what-are-review-tests-audits-and-how-do-they-work) for more ideas of how SE is trying to make sure people review and vote carefully.) Also, it's not the end of the world if you do make a mistake because it takes two people to confirm/reject an edit suggestion. [This meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work) also helps give a few more ideas on exactly how the whole Suggested Edit thing works, if you're curious.

Comment: Review audits sound really handy, why aren't they active on Arqade?